# Get node handle of parent - similar to findNodeHandle

Tags: react-native

Given a node handle obtained with `findNodeHandle`, is it possible to get the parent node handle?

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to get your child's parent's handler.

```js
import { findNodeHandle } from 'react-native';

const UIManager = require('NativeModules').UIManager;

const childHandler = findNodeHandle(this.refs.myElement);

UIManager.measureLayoutRelativeToParent(
  childHandler, 
  (e) => {console.error(e)}, 
  (x, y, w, h) => {
    console.log('offset', x, y, w, h);
  });
```

Comment: Thank you this is awesome, however I want to the handle to the parent, not the measurements. Is this possible?